# How do you click a javascript button using python selenium

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, html, selenium

I want to click this button on a webpage with selenium

heres the html for the button

```
<div class="wdpv_vote_up ">
  <input value="7787" type="hidden">
  <input class="wdpv_blog_id" value="1" type="hidden">
</div>
```

and heres the javascript for that

```
function voteUp() {
  if (!$(this).hasClass("wdpv_disabled")) {
    doVote($(this), "+1");
  }
  return false;
}
```

I want to be able to click that button but I dont know how , anny idea's ?

heres the post I want to auto like [here](http://www.facesoffactorie.com/?entry=8856)

Comment: You mean you are able to click this button manually?

Comment: yes I can click it manually but want to click it automatically

Comment: Have you tried clicking on the `div` tag, using selenium?

Comment: heres the post I want to like http://www.facesoffactorie.com/?entry=8856

Answer (score 0):

Try clicking the div-Element directly, like this:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("contains(@class, 'wdpv_vote_up')")).click();
```

I used xpath and contains, because your div-element's class attribute has a space included, don't know if this is a typo, or there might be other classes in the original code as well...

Comment: hey thanks for the help I am a bit confused , heres the page I want to auto like http://www.facesoffactorie.com/?entry=8856

Comment: @CamCoder hey buddy, what are you confused about?

Comment: I normally can click  buttons and fill out forms with selenium but with  this like button I have no idea http://www.facesoffactorie.com/?entry=8856